# remove date from filename but keep the file extension

Tags: bash, rename

I have files like these in a directory called current_dir:

```
my data-file 2014-10.txt
data file201409.txt
```

and I want

```
my data-file.txt
data file.txt
```

Here is what I tried

```
rename 's/ *[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{2}.*$//' current_dir/*.txt
```

but it removed the .txt extension as well.

I'm quite new to linux, could anyone help me?

Comment: when i look at your code it seams all of your files are txt, so your can simply rename them with your code and rename them again and add .txt to end of them

Answer (score 3):

rename only replaces the matched part so removing `.*$` from the regular expression keeps the `.txt`

```
rename 's/ *[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{2}//' current_dir/*.txt
```

---

Examples

```
$ rename -n 's/ *[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{2}//' *.txt
rename(data file201409.txt, data file.txt)
rename(my data-file 2014-10.txt, my data-file.txt)
```

Comment: `rename` is unfortunately not a standard command and there are multiple incompatible commands with this name. But the common ones all support *something like* this.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in `bash`. only if you are sure that the date part is right beside .txt extension on the left

```
cd $current_dir
for file in *.txt
do
  mv "$file" "${file%%[0-9]*.txt}
done
```

Comment: Hmm.. Wouldn't that result in `data file201409` and `my data-file 2014-10`?

Comment: Indeed, you need to add the `.txt` back on with something like `"${file%%[0-9]*.txt}.txt"`

Comment: The quotes aren't closed.